# How do I build Python WITHOUT OpenSSL?

Tags: python, openssl

I'm building my own Python binary.  I want to build it WITHOUT OpenSSL, since my app is released under the GPL and apparently the OpenSSL license is [incompatible with it](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#OpenSSL).

The Python `configure --help` command says that there is a `--without-PACKAGE` option for cases like this, but apparently that doesn't work for ssl:

```
$ ./configure --without-ssl
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-ssl
```

Any ideas here?

Edit: Here's a [mailing list item](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-April/600806.html) describing my issue, but it looks like the solution offered there is a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend trying to build Python with no OpenSSL. As can be verified with a simple grep lots of things would break if there was no SSL.

What you might look into instead is distributing your code with a modified GPL that allows linking with OpenSSL as an exception. An example of such a license text is on this email on debian-legal: https://lists.debian.org/debian-legal/2004/05/msg00595.html

Edit: I do **not** recommend this, but you can prevent the any linking to OpenSSL by running the following before ./configure:

```
sed -i'' -e '1i\
#error' ./Modules/_ssl.c
sed -i'' -e '1i\
#error' ./Modules/_hashopenssl.c
```

Notice that that is two commands both distributed on two lines. You can also manually add the #error as the first line of those files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I hadn't even considered this option.  Unfortunately, I do not have the legal expertise required to write such a modified license, or even evaluate the supposed legality of the license you linked to.  If possible, I'd much prefer a technical solution to this problem -- not a legal one.

Comment: I assure you that as long as you are distributing code where you are the copyright holder it is entirely legal to do something like this. Debian is a community that takes software freedom and legality seriously so if it's good enough for them, it should probably be good enough for you. Wikipedia has some additional examples of software that have similar exceptions to the GPL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL.

Comment: If you are not the sole copyright holder you will need to get the other copyright holders' approval to the license too.

Comment: I control the copyright of my own code, but I am forced to release it under the GPL because some of my dependencies are GPL.  Therefore, I believe I cannot release my code under a "modified GPL".

Comment: Why exactly are you building your own Python binary? If you were just distributing code written in Python you'd most probably be safe with just using the GPL, seeing as there are >4000 packages in PyPi with a GPL license: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=54&c=64

Comment: My Python project is about as complex as they come.  It relies on several Python extension modules, which use boost-python, sip, and cython to to provide python bindings.  These require linking directly against libpython, and I can't assume that the user's system python installation is the exact version that I used when building the extension modules.  The best solution is to simply include a binary of the python interpreter. This works quite well, except for this annoying legal issue...

Answer (score 0):

At least in Python 3.6, if you build Python in an environment which doesn't have headers of a dependent library, it will simply skip the modules which require it, giving a message like this:

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter
nis                   readline              spwd
zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```